# Corrected spelling error with spelling error

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3045077). I later realised that I corrected a spelling error with another spelling error.

I corrected "implicityly" with "implicity" instead of "implicitly".

Shouldn't this edit have been rejected instead of approved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit fixed several other issues in the post so no, it shouldn't be rejected just because of one mistake.

Improving it is the proper action for a reviewer, however many reviewers don't bother to do that.

In case such spelling fix is the only fix in an edit suggestion and it's wrong then the whole suggestion should be rejected.

Answer (score 6):

Read the section on who approved the edit more carefully:

> rgettman reviewed this 8 mins ago: **Edit**

Guess what he edited?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: But it had already been approved by 3 people

Comment: Yes, but at the same time that users decided to "improve" in stead of merely approve. Job done. Crisis averted.

Comment: @Bart true, for some reason took him a while to submit the edit probably to Google the correct spelling.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't recall taking more than about a minute or so to review this suggested edit.  I scanned the entire post for additional spelling/grammar fixes, which is why I chose "Edit" to correct "implicitly".  Addishunally, Im a gud speeler.  Their was know nede to googol the wurd.

Comment: @rgettman Yep, it wus joost the tyming.